# Strange behaviour of image preview in Windows user's %TEMP% folder

Tags: windows, image-viewer

This is something asked on a certain application's mailing list and it got me curious.

Say there are several images (any format, JPEG, PNG etc) in a folder. The default image preview application is active and double-clicking on any image will open it in the previewer. Using the arrow keys or arrow buttons of the application will then move to the previous or next image in the folder.

Now move the entire folder to `%TEMP%` (which in my case is `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp`)
Doing the same operation will open any image, but the previous & next operations are disabled. Selecting all the images, right-clicking and selecting preview will open one image with the previous & next functionality enabled. Why does this happen? It apparently only happens in the temporary folder (or a sub-folder).

Windows 7 Professional x64 Japanese edition, without any fancy customization.

Comment: Sounds like a deliberate software design limitation.  Its not unique to your installation just verified the behavior on a fresh Windows 7 virtual machine.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I was wondering whether it was some obscure limitation of the temporary folder, like `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` being unable to operate under certain conditions. However I can't find anything in the documentation and after slapping together a few lines of code, I've confirmed that the find functions work just fine.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem you're facing. As @Ramhound stated, it might be a limitation of the image viewer application you are using. Try switching to another image viewer app, maybe?